# Getting access is denied on opening SQL connections

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

We're pulling down data from SQL in a high throughput scenario here, through one app. Possibly up to 100+ SQL requests at any one time. Some may be long running, which may be why they mount up.

Intermittently (but not constantly), we're getting the following exception when calling `SqlConnection.Open();`:

> System.Exception: Error getting document from database --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>   at BridgeService.SqlDal.GetDataFromSql(Int32 entityId)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

The code causing this exception looks like this:

```
public DataSet GetDataFromSql(int entityId)
{
    DataSet tempDataSet = null;

    using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        cnn.Open(); // this line throws the exception

        try
        {
            // stuff gets done on cnn
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    return tempDataSet;
}
```

I'm imagining this is something to do with the connection pool in some way. Is there a way we can check for an available connection in the pool before we open and use it? Or is this caused by something completely different?

If you need any more info, feel free to ask.

Comment: It could be [network problems](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/64e31e18-6a0b-452c-a58e-0e3fab960606/sql-server-connectivity-issues?forum=sqldatabaseengine).

Comment: it could be one of the folowing problems : 1- uncorrect Server Adresse 2- uncorrect configuration of the server thus making it unreachable 3- you dont have the rights to connect to that server 4- the server is not propraly configured to be accessed from a remote connection

Comment: @Youness the error is **intermittent**

Comment: @stuartd  I'm checking that now. thanks. And you beat me to it with the reply :)

Comment: Verify with the network admin if he limited the concurrent connections on the sever. One wise kid cut me down to 50 connections to the SQL computer and thought it was more secure that way.

Comment: I suspect the intermittent connection problem is a symptom of different issue.  With 100+ concurrent queries, including long-running ones, the server may be too overloaded to respond to connection requests.  What sort of hardware is the SQL box running on?

Comment: You can run easily 500+ connections doing LRP (1 to 8 min each) on very limited server on a small VM like duo 2.8, 4 gig ram. It's slow but it doesn't disconnect. The piping does it's job fine. Obviously you need to set your client drop connection time to more than default 30 seconds. I have mine set to 180 seconds and it run fine on that test server

Comment: For what it's worth, [me too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41487778/7850) :-/

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem once too.Solved by enabling NamePipes in SQL server configuration manager and turning off windows firewall or allowing sqlserver port 1433 in windows firewall
Hope it'll work for you too

Comment: Sorry about the delay in replying. If this is the issue, why would it be intermitant? This isn't every time. It's only sometimes.

Comment: @CraigBrett did you ever find out how to fix this issue or what was causing it?

Comment: @Sturla: No, I don't think we did. I've moved on from the company where we were using the code, so I'm not sure entirely, but I'm fairly sure we just lived with this issue.

Comment: @CraigBrett Thanks for the reply. We finally discovered that sql machine had lots of strange event errors. It was just in a strange state. This just happened for no apparent reason. It all got fixed when we moved the database to another machine.

Answer (score 2):

That's outdated but if someone needs a solution,

Open Sql Configuration > Sql Server Network Configuration > Protocols for MSSQLServer
Then enable Named Pipes and TCP/IP settings.

Restart MSSql Server via windows services. [image: Named Pipes and TCP/IP settings]

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41487778/7850). Eventually we worked out that it wasn't a problem with SQL Server at all; it was a problem on the API server, where we were spinning up hundreds or even thousands of threads, each one making its own connection to the database. The API server couldn't handle the load and started throwing "Access Denied" exceptions without even really trying to connect.

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46930231/7850) was to throttle the number of threads. I used the pattern described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19709926/7850).